# Expo Android error message "Something went wrong 38.0.0 is not a valid SDK version"

Tags: react-native, expo, yarnpkg

I used Expo and all was fine with:

```
"expo": "^37.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Now I upgraded to the latest version via:

```
"expo": "^38.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.0.tar.gz",
```

This worked on the web version. But not on my Android device. Here I now get the following message:

> Something went wrong 38.0.0 is not a valid SDK version

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is an outdated version of the Expo Android app.

So if you probably have installed `2.15.1`. That's too old for `sdk-38.0.0`.

Going to the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent) tells that `2.16.1` is the latest version.

Install this and deploy again to your Android device and it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it with these instructions:

1. Close all your emulators
2. Install the latest version of expo cli:
   `npm i -g expo-cli`
3. Open your emulators
4. Re-install client:
   `expo client:install:android`
5. Then start expo  `expo start -c`